# Usage of the expression unfold against

Tags: expressions

Can I use the expression *unfold against* talking about some literature/movie/theatre actions. For example, *The plot of this performance unfolds against historical background*?

Comment: That's not quite the right way to look at this. "Against a historical background" is providing a context for "The plot... unfolds".

Comment: well... i'm quite sure, that i can say “plot unfolds”. can i use “against historical background” to continue this sentence?

Comment: You do need the "a" after "against" but apart from that yes the sentence seems fine to me. It's just not helpful to think of "unfold against" as an expression.

Comment: Rupe, how would you call this construction? I a freshman here, I'm not closely acquainted with your terminology.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a construction at all. I would say that "unfolds" and "against" are just words that happen to follow each other in the sentence. The structure of the sentence is *<X happens> <against a type of background>*. So for example you could also say things like "The action takes place against a background of civil unrest" or "The children grew up against a background of domestic violence", and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only can you do it, you'd be in good company--[authors have been unfolding things against both backgrounds and backdrops for years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unfolds+against+the+%2A%2Cunfolded+against+the+%2A&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), with backdrops being slightly more popular targets for unfolding than backgrounds. (The Pope, mystifyingly, comes in third.) Google News tells me that [about a dozen things](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unfolds+against+a+backdrop%22+OR+%22unfolds+against+the+backdrop%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+a+backdrop%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+the+backdrop%22&newwindow=1&hl=en&gl=us&authuser=0&tbm=nws&ei=UB-mU9igNMrfoAS_joLQDg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=625&dpr=1) have unfolded against backdrops of other things within the past month or so, compared to just [3 things](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&gl=us&authuser=0&tbm=nws&q=%22unfolds+against+a+background%22+OR+%22unfolds+against+the+background%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+a+background%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+the+background%22&oq=%22unfolds+against+a+background%22+OR+%22unfolds+against+the+background%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+a+background%22+OR+%22unfolded+against+the+background%22&gs_l=serp.3...7731.15675.0.15762.11.11.0.0.0.0.276.420.3j0j1.4.0....0...1c.1.47.serp..11.0.0.5zL1imnj5mY) unfolding against backgrounds.